# Observes Inject private final error

Tags: wildfly, kotlin

```
data class ExeEvent(val id: Long)


@Stateless
open class ExeManagerBean : IExeManagerBean {

 @Inject
    open val events: Event<ExeEvent>? = null


override fun listenTo(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) exeEvent: ExeEvent) {

    try {
        //doWork
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        logger.error("Fail. ex:$ex")
    }
}
```

On deploy app:

16:38:56,060 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."pay.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."bisys-pay-ear-worker.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000810: Cannot place qualifiers on final fields:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] @Inject private final ExeManagerBean.exeEvent

Answer (score 0):

You defined variable `events` as final because of `val` keyword and already set to `null`.

- change `val` to 'var':

  @Inject
  open var events: Event? = null
- use late initialization and `events` will be non-nullable type:

  @Inject
  open lateinit var events: Event

Comment: variable is open. For EJB defined variable as val work successfull